# how to bind different event to an element inside anchor tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i m using star rating plugin in jquery mobile to rate my docs my code is like this

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="page3-links">
        <img src="images/pdf.png">
            <h2>Books1</h2>
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>
        <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>
        <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>
        <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>
     </a>
</li>
```

my problem is i want to make click on    input but my anchor tag event is triggered whenever i clicks on the input and if i puts    input out of    anchor jquery mobiles formatting change and it looks very ugly what should i do

i try like this

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('.page3-links').click(function(){alert("hasdasi");});
    $('.page3-links input').unbind('click');
});
```

thank for your precious time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this by stopping the event propagation from input element. Try this

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('.page3-links').click(function(){alert("hasdasi");});
    $('.page3-links input').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the `click` from ever getting to the `.page3-links` element? Assuming that there is absolutely no whitespace allotted for the container internally?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the anchor from being followed you need to call `preventDefault` on the event variable.

```
$('.page3-links').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("hasdasi");
});
```